# ERC721 Contracts - why is _safeMint() always immediately calling yet another _safeMint()?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, nft, erc-721

When it comes time to do the actual ***minting***, it seems that every **ERC721** contract out there calls the **2**-argument version of the  `_safeMint()` function, which in turn then proceeds to immediately internally call the **3**-argument version of `_safeMint()`.

Here's what I mean - this is the code directly from OpenZeppelin's official **ERC721.sol** contract:

```
// The 2-argument version:
function _safeMint(address to, uint256 quantity) internal {
   // Immediately call the 3-argument version:
   _safeMint(to, quantity, "");
}



// And here's that 3-argument version:
function _safeMint(address to, uint256 quantity, bytes memory _data) internal {
   // minting logic/code, usually eventually calling:
   _mint();
}
```

So like I said, I've seen this pattern again and again and again, in pretty much every minting contract out there.

So I'm wondering if there's any reason why we can't just directly call the 3-argument version from ***our*** contract and skip that 2-argument version - since it all it seems to do is call the 3-argument version anyway - and be done with it?

Especially if we know we'll never have any real value for the `data` argument that has to get passed in, and can therefore just happily pass `""` for it ourselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call the 3 argument method immediately.

The two-argument version is provided with the default value for convenience during development. This way you don't need to figure out what default values need to apply to `_data` when it's not being used.

The reason the 2 argument version calls the three argument version is also for maintainability. If the 3 argument version is overridden, you still expect the 2 argument version to call the 3 argument version with the default value for `_data`.

The pattern is called overloading and is common in OOP languages like Java.
https://www.mygreatlearning.com/blog/method-overloading-in-java

Comment: Understood the 1st pt. of you answer - but not the 2nd. part. Can you give an example? (Who/Where would the 3-arg. version be overridden? And if it is overridden, wouldn't it be for the purpose of just calling it directly - and again skipping the 2-arg version anyway?)

Comment: When working with libraries (like OpenZeppelin) and complex contracts you might find a situation where you need to change the underlying implementation. In that case, you override the 3 arg version so that any methods using your 2 arg version are calling your updated code.

Comment: You could also call the 3 arg version directly, supplying your own value for the extra field. This multi-method pattern is called overloading and it's very common in OOP languages like Java

Comment: What's the purpose of that 3rd argument? I am using it so I can attach a string to each mint but I don't know how to access. Is it possible to access that `data` field somehow?